# Is there a way to block derived classes from further implementing a virtual function?

Tags: c++, oop, virtual-functions, c++03

It seems that in C++ (or is it general OOP concept?) the *once virtual always virtual* thing holds. I was wondering if there is anyway it can be stopped. I have this situation that needs what I am asking.

Let's say I have a Factory class like so

```
class Object;
class GeneralFactory
{
private:
    virtual Object* CreateObject() = 0;
};
```

Now I have a specialized factory which still lets object creation but with more control.

```
class SpecializedFactory : public GeneralFactory
{
private:
    virtual Object* CreateObject();
    virtual Object* DoCreateObject() = 0;
};
```

The idea is for the `SpecializedFactory::CreateObject` to use `DoCreateObject` in its implementation. But the way things are, a class can derive from `SpecializedFactory` and override the `CreateObject` undermining the good intentions.

Is what I am looking for possible, and valid, or the only way is for programmers to be good citizens and follow class hierarchy rules?

What is a suitable alternative? I am working with C++03 FYI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It seems that in C++ (or is it general OOP concept?) the once virtual
>   always virtual thing holds.

I would not call it *"once virtual always virtual"*, because that sounds a bit misleading. Virtuality is simply not the business of derived classes. Virtual functions are all about **base** clasess. It is the base class which needs to know whether a function is virtual or not, and make a virtual function call if necessary. The derived-class function may say *"I am not virtual anymore!"*, but who cares? It's been invoked through a virtual function call already at that point.

C++11 `final` does not change anything about this run-time behaviour, it just prevents overriding at compile time.

> Is what I am looking for possible, and valid, or the only way is for
>   programmers to be good citizens and follow class hierarchy rules?

In C++03, the easiest way would be good documentation and selecting only good programmers at job interviews :)

But that's probably not what you are looking for. A technical solution here would be to change your class design to a *has-a* relationship. **Workarounds to make entire classes final *do* exist in C++03.**

So, rather than `ConcreteSpecializedFactory` *is-a* `SpecializedFactory`, make it `SpecializedFactory` *has-a* `SpecializedFactoryImplementation`. You can then (optionally, for even more strictness) use `friend` to allow the latter to be called only from the former, and (and this is where the interesting part comes) you can use the **virtual inheritance trick** from the [C++ FAQ *"How can I set up my class so it won't be inherited from?"*](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/final-classes.html) to make the entire `SpecializedFactory` class final.

```
class SpecializedFactoryImplementation
{
public:
    virtual ~SpecializedFactoryImplementation() {}

private:
    SpecializedFactoryImplementation(SpecializedFactoryImplementation const &);
    SpecializedFactoryImplementation &operator=(SpecializedFactoryImplementation const &);

    friend class SpecializedFactory;

    Object* CreateObject()
    {
        return DoCreateObject();
    }

    virtual Object* DoCreateObject() = 0;
};

class SpecializedFactoryBase
{
private:
    friend class SpecializedFactory;
     SpecializedFactoryBase() {}
};

class SpecializedFactory : public GeneralFactory, private virtual SpecializedFactoryBase
{
// ...
public:
    SpecializedFactory(SpecializedFactoryImplementation* impl) :
        m_impl(impl)
    {
        // null checking omitted for simplicity
    }
private:

    // the GeneralFactory base class should not be copyable
    // anyway, so we do not have to worry about copy constructor
    // or assignment operator

    SpecializedFactoryImplementation* const m_impl;

    virtual Object* CreateObject()
    {
        return m_impl->CreateObject();
    }
};
```

The following will then not compile:

```
class SpecializedFactoryWrittenByEvilProgrammer : public SpecializedFactory
{
public:
    SpecializedFactoryWrittenByEvilProgrammer() : SpecializedFactory(0) {}
private:
    virtual Object* CreateObject()
    {
        return 0;
    }
};
```

And the following will not compile, either:

```
// somewhere outside of SpecializedFactory:
SpecializedFactoryImplementation *s;
s->CreateObject();
```

Comment: Looks like a nice start. Thanks.

Comment: A possible downside with the virtual inheritance trick is that it may increase the size of the objects of the class in memory (see [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20121208115058/http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/final-classes.html)).

Comment: Another reference for the virtual inheritance trick is Bjarne Stroustrup [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20111101181559/http://www2.research.att.com:80/~bs/bs_faq2.html#no-derivation). See also his book "The Design and Evolution of C++" sec 11.4.3.

Answer (score 3):

What you need is `final` keyword:

```
struct base {
   virtual void f();
};
struct derived : base {
   void f() final;       // virtual as it overrides base::f
};
struct mostderived : derived {
   //void f();           // error: cannot override!
};
```

Comment: then I guess there is no way as this is C++ feature.

Comment: @Dirt: If `final` was unnecessary then they wouldn't have added it to the next version of the language...

Comment: @Mehrdad I don't understand what made you comment "If final was unnecessary then they wouldn't have added it to the next version of the language.." to me. I didn't say it was unnecessary!

Comment: @Dirt: I meant if there was a way to achieve it in C++03 then it wouldn't have been necessary for them to introduce it in C++11.

Comment: @Mehrdad that logic doesn't hold; there are lots of things in C++11 that were possible in C++03, but simpler to express (e.g. iterating over a container)

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Yeah it doesn't in general, but in this particular case it does hold, given that the sole purpose of `final` is to prevent overriding. There aren't any other factors that come into play with `final` (no added convenience or anything), unlike with other features.