# How can I set up my class so it can't be inherited from in C++98/C++03?

Tags: c++, c++03, c++98

Using C++98 (or C++03), how can a class (`B`) be defined, such that no objects can be instantiated from a class (`D`) deriving from `B`.

```
struct B {};
struct D : public B {};
D d; // this should result in a compiler error
```

In C++11 (or newer) one could use the `final` specifier.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found these possible solutions, each with drawbacks:

##### "named constructors"

Define all constructors of the base class `private` and provide [named constructors](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#named-ctor-idiom) (`static`, `public` method which returns an object of that class).

Drawbacks:

- Using that class is ["not-so-clean"](https://microsoft.public.vc.language.narkive.com/hyMZXzQH/how-to-restrict-inheritance-in-c#post4) / less straightforward. The purpose of the effort should be to simplify using that class. The result requires more effort for *using* such classes.

##### "virtual inheritance trick"

I found this suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25581218/5534993) and from Bjarne Stroustrup [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20111101181559/http://www2.research.att.com:80/%7Ebs/bs_faq2.html#no-derivation). See also his book "The Design and Evolution of C++" sec 11.4.3.

The class for which inheritance shall be restricted (`B`), inherits (must be `public` *`virtual`* inheritance) from a helper class (`H`).
That helper class has only private constructors.
It has a `friend` relationship to the to-be restricted class `B`.
As only `B` may call the constructor of `H`, further successors of `B` can not be instantiated.

In contrast to the "named constructors" solutions the "usual" constructor can be called.
I consider this more straightforward for using that class.

Drawbacks:

- Usually this will increase the size of objects of `B` in memory because of the *`virtual`* inheritance. See [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20121208115058/http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/final-classes.html).
- It requires more effort for *programming* such classes.

Comment: Defining all destructors of the base class `private` does prevent to create objects of a derived class as long as they are automatically deleted. Which usually means that they must be created with `new` and `delete` is never called.